# Re-arranging the equation $L=\sqrt{a^2\sin^2t+b^2\cos^2t\,}$ to find $\left(t\right)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I re-array the equation

> $L=\sqrt{a^2\sin^2t+b^2\cos^2t\,}$

to find the equation of $\left(t\right)$ ?

> $t=\,?$

I tried to solve it but I'm stuck at:

> $L^2=a^2\sin^2t+b^2\cos^2t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\cos^2 t+\sin^2 t = 1$

**`SOLUTION:`**

> $L^2=\left(\sqrt{a^2\sin^2t+b^2\cos^2t\,}\right)^2$
>
> $L^2=a^2\sin^2t+b^2\cos^2t$
>
> $L^2=a^2\sin^2t+b^2\left(1-\sin^2t\right)$
>
> $L^2=a^2\sin^2t+b^2-b^2\sin^2t$
>
> $L^2=\sin^2t\,\left(a^2-b^2\right)+b^2$
>
> $L^2-b^2=\sin^2t\,\left(a^2-b^2\right)$
>
> $\sin^2t=\frac{L^2-b^2}{a^2-b^2}$
>
> $\sqrt{\sin^2t}=\sqrt{\frac{L^2-b^2}{a^2-b^2}}$
>
> $\sin t=\sqrt{\frac{L^2-b^2}{a^2-b^2}}$
>
> $\arcsin \left(\sin t\right)=\arcsin \left(\sqrt{\frac{L^2-b^2}{a^2-b^2}}\right)$
>
> $t=\arcsin \left(\sqrt{\frac{L^2-b^2}{a^2-b^2}}\right)$

Comment: $t=\arccos \left(\frac{L^2-a^2}{b^2-a^2}\right)^2$ ??

Comment: $t=\arccos \sqrt{\frac{L^2-a^2}{b^2-a^2}}$

Comment: provided sqrt and arccos are defined